# Python module failure

Tags: python, module, cassandra

I'm learning the Cassandra object mapper using Python, and I have the following small program that populates a database table.  This works just fine...

```
from cassandra.cqlengine.connection import setup
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from uuid import uuid4

##import Courses

class Courses(Model):
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key = True)
    title  = columns.Text()
    duration = columns.Integer()

setup(['chelly', ], 'objectlake', protocol_version = 3)

# Create some courses to inflict on our hapless trainees

courses = [
    { 'title' : "Conflict of Interest" , 'duration' : 120 },
    { 'title' : "Resolving Conflict" ,   'duration' : 60 },
    { 'title' : "Time Cards" ,           'duration' : 30 },
    { 'title' : "PTO" ,                  'duration' : 30 },
    { 'title' : "Managing Upwards" ,     'duration' : 120 }
]

sync_table(Courses)

for course in courses:
    Courses.create(id = uuid4(), title = course['title'], duration = course['duration'])

print('Done-ish?')
```

But, if I comment the definition of the Courses class and uncomment the import, with this in Courses.py:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns

class Courses(Model):
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key = True)
    title  = columns.Text()
    duration = columns.Integer()
```

I get an exception `ValueError: Models must be derived from base Model.` on the `sync_table` call.  I'm certain I've pooched moving the declaration of the class into the module, but can't find what I've done wrong.  I'm not sure why my object from the module isn't a Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `import Courses`, the name `Courses` will refer to the *module* called `Courses`, and *not* the class `Courses` that happens to be inside this module.

The function you’re using requires that its argument be derived from a certain class, and the *module* `Courses` obviously doesn’t satisfy this condition.

You probably meant to import the *class* called `Courses` like this:

```
from Courses import Courses
```

Comment: _Groan!_ Yes, that's it!  I was pretty certain it was something simple.